# Adicionar numero ao clicar no botao Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Queria adicionar um input de um numero qualquer, adicionar ele em uma caixa e pegar esse valor e sempre que apertar no botão adicionar um numero, alguém pode me ajudar?

ex:

```js
function inserir() {
  var total = document.getElementById('valor').value;
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = total;
}

function entrou() {}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="valor"><br><br>
<button class="botao" onclick="inserir()">Inserir</button><br>
<p id="resultado"></p>
<button class="botao" onclick="entrou()">Entrou</button>
```

e não consigo sair daqui, já tentei de varias formas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função insertAdjacentText() do JavaScript, esse método insere um texto em uma posição especifica. Tente dessa maneira:

```
function inserir() {
      var total = document.getElementById('valor').value;      
      document.getElementById('resultado').insertAdjacentText('afterend', total)
}
```

Se quiser saber mais sobre a função visite: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacenttext.asp